# Scikit learn spectral clustering get items per cluster

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am trying to cluster terms present in text documents using spectral clustering. After doing clustering I would like to get the terms present in each cluster.

The code I tried is as follows,

```
    true_k = 4
    vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words='english',decode_error='ignore')
    X = vectorizer.fit_transform(documents)
    terms = vectorizer.get_feature_names()
    model = SpectralClustering(n_clusters=true_k ,eigen_solver='arpack',affinity='nearest_neighbors')
    model.fit(X)
```

From here I am stuck to get the terms per cluster, using 'labels_' doesn't help as it only returns the cluster labels

**Edit : Solved** , The code below did the trick,

```
    print("Terms per cluster:")
    for i in range(true_k):
        print "Cluster %d:" % i,
        T=X[model.labels_==i].indices
        for ind in T:
            print terms[ind]
        print
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you must first fit the model, i.e. `model.fit(X)`. To access elements of `X` belonging to cluster `k` according to the fitted model, do `X[model.labels_==k]`.